# Show that a simple ring is always an algebra over some field

Tags: ring-theory, representation-theory

> Show that a simple ring $R$ is always an algebra over some field.

So I need to show that there exist a field $k$ such that there exists a ring homomorphism $\phi : k \to Z(R) $.

In an earlier exercise I've proven that a simple commutative ring is a field.

Any hints how to tackle this problem ?

Comment: Is $Z(R)$ simple?

Comment: @Hurkyl I think so. If it wouldn't be simple it would contain an nontrivial ideal, but then $R$ also has a nontrivial ideal.

Answer (score 3):

If $a$ is nonzero and in the center, then the two sided ideal $aR=R$. Thus, the center is a field.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Is this still true if we do not assume the ring to be unital (i.e. we are no longer sure to have any non-zero central elements)?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft If the center has a nonzero idempotent $e$, then $eR=R=R^2$. You can then view R as a cyclic idempotent ideal of a ring with unity, and then Nakayama's lemma proves R has an identity. To break this, we'd have to go to algebras over rings without identities, I guess...